# how do i know what to use in/on/from/in/at + which?

Tags: pronouns

I can see similar questions about this in/from/at .. +which .. but I don't really get it so I want to ask few things

It's a sentence from my textbook.

> 1. She describes a personal experience **in which** the dean asked her if she could give him a ride home.
> 2. Chaos theory attempts to explain systems **in which** a small difference in initial conditions can drastically change the final outcome.

I don't think I understand it fully. I can't really say why there is "**in which**".

Comment: *Which* is a demonstrative pronoun that refers back to whatever it happens to refer back to in the sentence at hand. The choice of preposition has nothing to do with *which* and everything to do with the thing it refers to. If it's "in the experience", then it is "experience in which". If it's "to the experience", then it's "experience to which". If it's "on top of the experience", then it's "experience on top of which". If it's "out from behind the experience", then it's "experience out from behind which".

Comment: "Which" is a relative pronoun serving as complement of "in". The pronoun has "personal experience" and "systems" as antecedents. "Experience" and "systems"  select the preposition "in". It's just something you'll have to become familiar with.